# Updating Database Command in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, sql, database

```
        using (MySqlCommand bb = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE  members SET  Begin = 1 WHERE id ='" + uid + "';"))
        {
            bb.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand fff = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE  members SET  b = 1 WHERE id ='" + uid + "';"))
            {
                fff.Connection = con;
            }
            this.Hide();
            Main main = new Main();
            main.Show();
        }
```

I'm trying to update both tables, B and Begin to 1 to the current logged in user (my uid command:

```
  using (MySqlCommand id = new MySqlCommand("SELECT id FROM members WHERE username='" + textBox1.Text + "';"))
                            {
                                id.Connection = con;
                                MySqlDataReader read3 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                                read3.Dispose();
                                int idd = (int)id.ExecuteScalar();
                                uid = idd;
                                Begin.uid = idd;
                                MySqlDataReader read4 = id.ExecuteReader();
                                read4.Dispose();
                                id.Dispose();
                            }
```

I don't know why but it doesn't update the database.

Comment: You never execute the update command.

Comment: Exactly What @GrantThomas said, and this command is vulnerable to "SQL Injection". And better yet, it's freaking 2013, stop using direct SQL!! use a entity framework, all this problems will go away....

Comment: Not only that, you need to use a parameterised update.

Answer (score 5):

You're not executing the command.

You need `fff.ExecuteScalar();`
And `bb.ExecuteScalar();`

Or `ExecuteNonQuery();`

Also you are vulnerable to `SQL Injection`, try using [paramerterized queries](http://johnhforrest.com/2010/10/parameterized-sql-queries-in-c/).

For instance:

```
 bb.CommandText = "UPDATE members SET  Begin = 1 WHERE id = @id";  
 bb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
 bb.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks! How can i make in unvulnerable to SQL inj?:) idk what are paramerterized queries.. xD

Comment: @VlasiuRobert - updated the answer to show you how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all user parametrized querys, second you do call `ExecuteNonQuery()` on any of your `SqlCommands`.

```
using (MySqlCommand bb = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE  members SET  Begin = 1 WHERE id = @id;"))
{
    bb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", uid);
    bb.Connection = con;
    con.Open();

    bb.ExecuteNonQuery();

    using (MySqlCommand fff = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE  members SET  b = 1 WHERE id = @id;"))
    {
        fff.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", uid);
        fff.Connection = con;

        fff.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    this.Hide();
    Main main = new Main();
    main.Show();
}
```